# C++ tellg() return type

Tags: c++

I have a large binary file that I am reading and I would like to compare the current position with an unsigned long long int. However, based on the C++ documentation, it isn't clear to me if:

1. What is the return type of tellg()
2. How can I compare tellg() with the unsigned long long int?
3. Is it possible that the return type of tellg() has a maximum value (from numeric_limits) that is smaller than an unsigned long long int?

Any answers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pos_type`, which is the return type of `tellg()`, is determined by the traits template argument.  Not much more is guaranteed in any portable way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q** What is the return type of tellg()?

**A** The return type of `istream::tellg()` is `streampos`. Check out [std::istream::tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/?kw=tellg).

**Q** How can I compare tellg() with the unsigned long long int?

**A** The return value of `tellg()` is an integral type. So you can use the usual operators to compare two `int`s. However, you are not supposed to do that to draw any conclusions from them. The only operations that the standard claims to support are:

> Two objects of this type can be compared with operators == and !=. They can also be subtracted, which yields a value of type streamoff.

Check out [std::streampos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streampos/).

**Q** Is it possible that the return type of tellg() has a maximum value (from numeric_limits) that is smaller than an unsigned long long int?

**A** The standard does not make any claims to support it or refute it. It might be true in one platform while false in another.

### Additional Info

**Comparing `streampos`, examples of supported and unsupported compare operations**

```
ifstream if(myinputfile);
// Do stuff.
streampos pos1 = if.tellg();
// Do more stuff
streampos pos2 = if.tellg();

if ( pos1 == pos2 ) // Supported
{
   // Do some more stuff.
}

if ( pos1 != pos2 ) // Supported
{
   // Do some more stuff.
}

if ( pos1 != pos2 ) // Supported
{
   // Do some more stuff.
}

if ( pos1 == 0 ) // supported
{
   // Do some more stuff.
}

if ( pos1 != 0) // supported
{
   // Do some more stuff.
}

if ( pos1 <= pos2 ) // NOT supported
{
   // Do some more stuff.
}


int k = 1200;
if ( k == pos1 ) // NOT supported
{
}
```

Comment: `tellg()` actually returns `pos_type` (§27.7.2.3/39) which isn't necessarily `std::streampos`. The reference you linked to is inaccurate. [Try this one.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for the pointer. For what it's worth, on further digging, `istream::pos_type` ends up being defined as `std::streampos`. This is how I got there. `istream` -> `char_traits<char>` -> `pos_type`.

Comment: Wait, so you can compare them but you aren't suppose to draw any conclusions form them? Then why else would you compare them?

Comment: @slaw I added more information to the answer to answer your question.

Comment: Okay, so if I want to perform the "supported" comparison then I should store the tellg() into a streampos rather than an unsigned long long int?

Comment: comparison to 0 is missing

Comment: @StepanYakovenko, indeed. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

R Sahu did a good job on answering the questions, however I was getting overflows when storing the result of `.tellg()` in an `int` and did some extra investigation.

### TL;DR: Use `std::streamoff` (read as "stream offset") as a integer type to store the result of `tellg()`.

From browsing [std::basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream):

```
pos_type tellg();
```

where the `pos_type` is defined by the `Traits` template arguments, which in turn is implementation defined. For std::ifstream the Traits is [std::char_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) of type char, which leads to [std::fpos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos). Here we see:

> **Each object of type fpos holds the byte position in the stream (typically as a private member of type std::streamoff**) and the current shift state, a value of type State (typically std::mbstate_t).

(bolding done by me)

Hence, to avoid overflows it should be safe to cast the result of `tellg()` to whatever the type of `std::streamoff` is. Further, checking [std::streamoff](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff) it says

> The type std::streamoff is a signed integral type of sufficient size to represent the maximum possible file size supported by the operating system. Typically, this is a typedef to **long long**.

---

As the exact type is defined by your system, it's probably a good idea to run a quick test. Here is the result on my machine:

```
std::cout << "long long:" std::is_same<std::ifstream::off_type, long long>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << "long:" std::is_same<std::ifstream::off_type, long>::value << std::endl;

// Outputs
// long long:0
// long:1
```